# Laravel Horizon - Settings in job model like "retryAfter", "tries" or "timeout" not working

Tags: php, laravel, horizon, laravel-horizon

I'm running Laravel Horizon but I noticed that the setting in the Job model like `public $retryAfter` or `public $tries` or `public $timeout` do not working (Laravel doc: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs).

For example to retry a failed Job for 4 times, the:

```
public $retryAfter = 4;
```

does not work, but works setting `'tries' => 4` in the `horizon.php` config file:

```
        'local' => [
            'supervisor-1' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => ['default'],
                'balance' => 'simple',
                'processes' => 3,
                'tries' => 4,
            ],
        ],
```

Why these settings on a per-job basis do not work with Horizon and do not override general settings?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, think I found the problem... I'm using Laravel-Horizon 5.7 that doesn't implement the `$retryAfter` variable.

Answer (score 0):

`public $tries` works for sure. I have it in my project.

`public $retryAfter` value is the number of seconds to wait before retrying the job. It does not mean the number of times to retry a job

`public $timeout` value means keeping trying the job until a point in time has passed (e.g. 5 mins in the future)

You can check by setting `public $tries = 1` , while having `tries => 4` in horizon.php. Remember to kill your horizon process `php artisan horizon:terminate` and start it again with `php artisan horizon`

Comment: Ok, `public $tries` works, sorry for my question... but `public $retryAfter` doesn't. It should override (if I understand correctly) the `'delay' => 0,` in `horizon.php` config file. Is this true? Now, with `public $tries = 5;` the Job are re-tried for 5 times but without waiting the `$retryAfter` value.